# ajax autosearch in codeigniter

Tags: php, ajax, codeigniter

What is this **"domhos/view"** in this code mean? Is this view?

**Controller  search.php**

```
public function autocomplete() {
    $search_data = $this->input->post('search_data');
    $query = $this->Model_Domain->get_autocomplete($search_data);

    foreach ($query->result() as $row):
        echo "<li><a href='" . base_url() . "domhos/view/" . $row->id . "'>" . $row->domain_name . "</a></li>";
    endforeach;
}
```

Comment: `domhos` id your controller name and `view` is your function name inside your controller

Answer (score 1):

**script**

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function ajaxSearch() {
        var input_data = $('#search_data').val();
           $.ajax({

                type: "POST",
                url: "<?php echo base_url(); ?>home/autocomplete",
                data: {id2:input_data},
                success: function(data) {
                if (data.length > 0) {
                $('#suggestions').show();
                $('#autoSuggestionsList').addClass('auto_list');
                $('#autoSuggestionsList').html(data);
                    }
                }
            });
    }

  </script>
```

**controller**

```
         public function autocomplete() 
         {
            $search_data = $this->input->post('id2');
            $client_details= $this->home_model->get_client_search($search_data);

           foreach ($client_details->result() as $row) 
           {
               echo $row->client_name .'</br>' ;

           }

        }
```

**view**

```
    <div class="something">
    <input name="search_data" id="search_data" type="text" onkeyup="ajaxSearch();">
    <div id="suggestions">
        <div id="autoSuggestionsList">  
        </div>
    </div>
```

**model**

```
          function get_client_search($search_data)
     {
        $this->db->select('client_id,client_name');
        $this->db->like('client_name', $search_data);
        return $this->db->get('ms_client', 10);
     }
```